# Are there any resonant frequency spectra that do not possess any harmonics?

Tags: waves, acoustics, terminology, superposition, harmonics

I’m hoping that somebody can help clarify the following passage regarding standing waves and the systems that support them:

> Many systems that support standing waves have resonant frequency spectra in which the resonant frequencies are not integral multiples of the lowest frequency. In all resonant frequency spectra, the lowest resonant frequency is called the fundamental frequency (or just the fundamental), the next lowest resonant frequency is called the first overtone, the next lowest the second overtone, and so forth . . . Only if each resonant frequency is an integral multiple of the fundamental frequency are they referred to as harmonics.

I’m comfortable with the idea that certain systems that support standing waves (such as the membrane of a drum) possess inharmonic resonance frequencies that are not integral multiples of the system’s lowest-frequency resonance frequency (the fundamental frequency), in addition to harmonic resonance frequencies that *are* integral multiples of the fundamental. One possible interpretation of the preceding passage is that there exist systems with resonance frequency spectra in which there are no harmonic frequencies—that is, any integral multiple of the lowest fundamental frequency is not itself a resonance frequency. Is this the correct interpretation of the passage/are there any existing systems that meet these (stricter) criteria?

I’m also not totally clear on the final sentence of the the passage, which concerns the terminology of resonance frequencies. If read literally, it seems to imply that if a system possesses any resonance frequencies that are not integral multiples of the fundamental frequency (like the membrane of a drum), then those resonance frequencies that *are* integral multiples of the fundamental frequency can no longer be classified as harmonics. This interpretation does not seem to be consistent with most of the material I’ve found online, but can anybody comment on this aspect of the nomenclature of resonant frequency spectra?

Comment: In practice, either *all* the resonant frequencies are integer multiples of the fundamental frequency (at least to a good approximation) or *none* of them are. There is not much use for having a terminology for the case where some are and some are not. (Note, even in a piano or a guitar, none of the resonant frequencies of a string are *exact* harmonics if you measure the frequency accurately enough, Look up "inharmonicity" on Google. But assuming they *are* harmonics is a useful approximation.

Comment: OK—so if I understand correctly, harmonicity is an idealization, and the resonance frequencies of instruments like pianos and guitars are near enough to integral multiples of some fundamental frequency to be considered harmonics. The resonance frequencies of a drum, on the other hand, deviate from any integral multiple pattern by enough to (somewhat subjectively) be characterized as inharmonic resonance frequencies. Is this about right?

Comment: Yep, I believe that this is the summary of what alephzero has already nicely mentioned. Harmonicity is very well "a thing" we consider mainly from a psychoacoustic point of view. Little is physics concerned about harmonicity when there's no one to "perceive" it. So, in that sense, people care about out mainly out of musical interest. For example, the seventh partial/overtone of a piano is the most "out of tuning" overtone and this is why designers try to suppress it by "strucking" the strings on about 1/7th  of their length.